# Android Toast prevents my devices to sleep

Tags: android, toast

I use Toast to indicate my app's state. And I use the following code in order to control toast showing time.

```
Toast noCardDetectedToast=null;
void setVisibilityNoCardDetectedToast(boolean visible)
{
    if(visible)
    {
        if(noCardDetectedToast==null)
            noCardDetectedToast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_card_detected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        noCardDetectedToast.show();
    }
    else
    {
        if(noCardDetectedToast!=null)
        {
            noCardDetectedToast.cancel();
            noCardDetectedToast=null;
        }
    }
}
```

When it's necessary to show this Toast, the application starts invoking *setVisibilityNoCardDetectedToast(true)* several times per second.
And when the application doesn't need this toast any more, it invokes *setVisibilityNoCardDetectedToast(false)*.

Everything works fine, but my android device does not fall asleep, as long as the toast is visible.(I tested my application on Android 4.x and 5.0)
This behaviour looks strange for me. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Device won't sleep if the toast is showing. This is a standard behaviour of Android.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you.